# PHP Convert Semantic Versioning String To Integer/Float

Tags: php, versioning, semantics

I have a `string` variable in `PHP` storing the current version of my application in semantic versioning format:

```
 $version = "0.2.6";
```

How can I convert this to an integer or float where I can do things compare versions using `<`  and `>`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a special [`version_compare()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.version-compare.php) function in php

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the necromancy, but there is now a packagist package, [vierbergenlars/php-semver](https://packagist.org/packages/vierbergenlars/php-semver), that can be included with composer.